# What' s the asymptotic behaviour of this integral?

Tags: integration, asymptotics

In $\mathbb R^N$ we assume that $p>1$ is some constant, $U$ is radial and positive, $U'(r)<0$ for all $r>0$. Moreover, $U$ and $U'$ have the following asymptotic behaviour
$$\lim_{r\to+\infty}r^{\frac{N-1}{2}}e^{\sqrt{p}r}U(r)=a>0,\quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{r\to+\infty}\frac{U'(r)}{U(r)}=-\sqrt{p}.$$
Now for $y=(y_1,y_2,0,\dots,0)$ I want to estimate this integral
$$\int_{B_\frac{|y|}{2}(0)}U(x-y)U^p(x)\partial_1U(x)dx.$$
There seems to be some estimates such as
$$\int_{B_\frac{|y|}{2}(0)}U(x-y)U^p(x)dx\sim e^{-\sqrt{p}|y|}|y|^{-\frac{N-1}{2}},\quad\text{and}\quad \int_{B_\frac{|y|}{2}(0)}U(x-y)\partial_1U(x)dx\sim -e^{-\sqrt{p}|y|}|y|^{-\frac{N-1}{2}}y_1.$$
Therefore I guess my integral may behave like them as well but I can't work it out.